# DataFrame only keep higher/lower values

Tags: python, pandas

I am trying to clean up a dataset. Only values smaller than the last value should be kept.

Right now it look slike this:

```
   my_data
0       10
1        8
2        7
3       10
4        5
5        8
6        2
```

after the cleanup it should look like this:

```
   my_data
0       10
1        8
2        7
3        7
4        5
5        5
6        2
```

I also have some working code but I am looking for a faster and more pythonic way of doing it.

```
import pandas as pd

df_results = pd.DataFrame()
df_results['my_data'] = [10, 8, 7, 10, 5, 8, 2]

data_idx = list(df_results['my_data']._index)
for i in range(1, len(df_results['my_data'])):
    current_value = df_results['my_data'][data_idx[i]]
    last_value = df_results['my_data'][data_idx[i - 1]]

    df_results['my_data'][data_idx[i]] = current_value if current_value < last_value else last_value
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use:

```
In [53]: df[df.my_data.diff() > 0] = np.nan

In [54]: df
Out[54]: 
   my_data
0     10.0
1      8.0
2      7.0
3      NaN
4      5.0
5      NaN
6      2.0

In [55]: df.ffill()
Out[55]: 
   my_data
0     10.0
1      8.0
2      7.0
3      7.0
4      5.0
5      5.0
6      2.0
```

Comment: I might have accepted the answer too early, I have problems with floating point numbers. [10, 8, 7, 10, 5, 8, 2, 2.1, 2.01, 3, 1]

Comment: the first line returns [10.0, 8.0, 7.0, nan, 5.0, nan, 2.0, nan, 2.01, nan, 1.0]

Comment: @HennyKo This is what you want, what's wrong with this result ? What did you expect ?

Comment: [10.0, 8.0, 7.0, nan, 5.0, nan, 2.0, nan, nan, nan, 1.0] because 2.01 is bigger than 2.0

Comment: @HennyKo Then just use `df.cummin()`.Though this is contradictory to your question: "Only values smaller than the *last value* should be kept."

Comment: Thank you, sorry for not clearly asking the question.

Answer (score 1):

I am using `shift` with `diff`

```
s=df.my_data.diff().gt(0)
df.loc[s,'my_data']=df.loc[s.shift(-1).fillna(False),'my_data'].values

Out[71]: 
   my_data
0     10.0
1      8.0
2      7.0
3      7.0
4      5.0
5      5.0
6      2.0
```